# localhost gnome-shell[2503]: Object Meta.Background (0x561c9cb0e990), has been already deallocated

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

This is:

```
lsb_release -crid
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

apt-cache policy gnome-shell
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500

uname -a
Linux localhost 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The system was updated this past Thursday via Software Updater when told a new release was available. There were no glitches and the system booted into 18.04.1 normally. I've been seeing quite a few notations in my syslog that I fail to understand so I'll be asking quite a few questions. The entire notation from the above subject is:

```
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost gnome-shell[2503]: Object Meta.Background (0x561c9cb0e990), has been already deallocated - impossible to access to it. This might be caused by the fact that the object has been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: == Stack trace for context 0x561c9a54e330 ==
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #0 0x561c9a9edd60 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/background.js:718 (0x7febd000f450 @ 22)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #1 0x561c9a9edcd8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:113 (0x7febd02c7e68 @ 37)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #2 0x7fff0e3e0e80 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:208 (0x7febd02d3b38 @ 54)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #3 0x7fff0e3e0fd0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:337 (0x7febd02d3bc0 @ 1626)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #4 0x7fff0e3e1080 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:350 (0x7febd02d3c48 @ 100)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #5 0x561c9a9edc60 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:365 (0x7febd02d3cd0 @ 10)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #6 0x7fff0e3e2400 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7febd02d3230 @ 386)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #7 0x561c9a9edbd0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:245 (0x7febd02cf808 @ 159)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #8 0x7fff0e3e3760 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7febd02b5de0 @ 71)
Aug 18 18:09:43 localhost org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2503]: #9 0x561c9a9edb50 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:220 (0x7febd02cf780 @ 15)
```

Appreciate any help in understanding what's going on and if this is a problem and not just information being posted, a fix.

Comment: I get this error a couple times a week and it crashes my desktop session. Very annoying.